# Show user ID in admin/people list?

Tags: users

How difficult would it be to show a column in the user list (admin/people) that shows the user's ID number? Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty easy if you're able to install the [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.

It replaces the default admin/people page with a view, which you can easily customise to add the user id as another column in the table.

If you're not able to use that module there are ways to do it in code, but it's a bit fiddly. I did roughly the same thing a couple of months ago (before I'd come across Admin Views) so let me know if you want me to dig the code out and post it here.

Comment: Excellent suggestion Clive, this looks very promising. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Jolva: If this answer worked for you, you can [accept](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it to give an extra thank-you to the answerer -- they get some extra rep points and it helps others find the 'best' answer.

Answer (score 5):

Implement `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` in a custom module to add the `uid` column to the list of people:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $uid_column = array('uid' => array(
    'data'  => 'ID',
    'field' => 'u.uid'
  ));
  $form['accounts']['#header'] = $uid_column + $form['accounts']['#header'];

  foreach ($form['accounts']['#options'] as $key => $row) {
    $form['accounts']['#options'][$key]['uid'] = $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - this method should work with fields added via Profile2 right? Thanks scronide!

Comment: It could, but it would take a lot more work because that form only knows values in the user table by default. If you needed to pull in Profile2 fields, I'd suggest going the Views route.

Comment: Very useful for the ID. Note that it can't easily be extended to include the email address as it's not included in the query.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the profile2 fields you can just tweak the code like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_user_admin_account_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $uid_column = array('uid' => array(
    'data'  => 'ID',
    'field' => 'u.uid'
  ));
  $form['accounts']['#header'] = $uid_column + $form['accounts']['#header'];

  foreach ($form['accounts']['#options'] as $key => $row) {
    $userProfile = user_load($key);  // this will have all user profile object which can be used below instead of $key.

    $form['accounts']['#options'][$key]['uid'] = $key;  // replace $key with the object value you need.
  }
}
```